# I am trying to make a password strength tester using a point system. VB.net

Tags: vb.net

The code must add and subtract points based on the following criteria.

+5 for having one upper case

+5 for having one lower case

+5 for one digit

+5 for having one of these symbols !"$%^&()_-

-5 only containing upper case

-5 for only containing lowercase

-5 for only containing digits

-5 for only containing symbols

I am struggling to make the code add 5 points once per criteria instead of multiple times any help would be appreciated in VB.net. Sorry forgot to post my code.

```
       points = Len(password)
    counter = 1
    While counter < Len(password) + 1
        letter = GetChar(password, counter)
        convletter = Asc(letter)

        'Ascii values for uppercase exclusive
        If 64 < convletter < 91 Then
            'Adds 5 points
            points = points + 5
            'Ascii values for lowercase letters exclusive
        ElseIf 96 < convletter < 123 Then
            'If letter is lowercase + 5 points
            points = points + 5
            'Ascii values for digits exclusive
        ElseIf 47 < convletter < 58 Then
            points = points + 5

        End If

        counter = counter + 1
    End While

    Console.WriteLine(points)
    Console.ReadLine()
```

I need the code to cycle through the letters of the string but only add 5 points once instead of repeatedly how could I solve this. *Sorry I'm new round here

Comment: Can't quite see your screen from here. Can you post your code?

Comment: Can  you show what code you have right now, and what exactly you're having an issue with?  This actually seems very straightforward.

Comment: @KenWhite Does this help?

Comment: @user2366842 does this help?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Does this help ?

Comment: I hope you aren't really trying to implement password strength like that.   Read https://www.theverge.com/2017/8/7/16107966/password-tips-bill-burr-regrets-advice-nits-cybersecurity

Comment: But basically, rather than adding points in a loop, have some boolean variables for each rule. Initialise them to false.  In the loop set them to true if it matches the rule.   After the loop, check each boolean and add the points when true.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf - my bets are this is more of a school exercise as opposed to a real production block of code (or at least so I'd hope).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim UpCase As Boolean = False
Dim LowCase As Boolean = False
Dim Digit As Boolean = False
Dim Symbol As Boolean = False
Dim UpCaseOnly As Boolean = False
Dim LowCaseOnly As Boolean = False
Dim SymbolOnly As Boolean = False
Dim DigitOnly As Boolean = False
Dim Password As String = "!" & chr(34) & "/$%?&*()-_"
Dim Points As Integer = Password.Length
'check password
For Each xChar As Char In Password
    Select Case xChar
        Case "A" To "Z"
            UpCase = True
        Case "a" To "z"
            LowCase = True
        Case "0" To "9"
            Digit = True
        Case "!" To "/", "_" 'ascii 33 to 47 !"/$%?&*()- and 95 _ '
            Symbol = True
    End Select
Next
If (Symbol = True) And (UpCase = False) And (LowCase = False) And (Digit = False) Then SymbolOnly = True
If (Symbol = False) And (UpCase = True) And (LowCase = False) And (Digit = False) Then UpCaseOnly = True
If (Symbol = False) And (UpCase = False) And (LowCase = True) And (Digit = False) Then LowCaseOnly = True
If (Symbol = False) And (UpCase = False) And (LowCase = False) And (Digit = True) Then DigitOnly = True

'check for points
If SymbolOnly = True Then Points -= 5
If UpCaseOnly = True Then Points -= 5
If LowCaseOnly = True Then Points -= 5
If DigitOnly = True Then Points -= 5
If (LowCaseOnly = False) And (LowCase = True) Then Points += 5
If (UpCaseOnly = False) And (UpCase = True) Then Points += 5
If (DigitOnly = False) And (Digit = True) Then Points += 5
If (SymbolOnly = False) And (Symbol = True) Then Points += 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim symbols = "!""$%^&()_-"

Dim plusses = { _
        password.Any(Function(c) symbols.Contains(c)), _
        password.Any(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)), _
        password.Any(Function(c) Char.IsUpper(c)), _
        password.Any(Function(c) Char.IsLower(c)) _
    }.Where(Function (x) x).Count() * 5

Dim minusses = { _
        password.All(Function(c) symbols.Contains(c)), _
        password.All(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)), _
        password.All(Function(c) Char.IsUpper(c)), _
        password.All(Function(c) Char.IsLower(c)) _
    }.Where(Function (x) x).Count() * 5     

Dim score = plusses - minusses
```